# click anywhere to close dropdown in react

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have multiple custom build dropdown component of react on a page. I trigger the list item to open using setState

```
toggleDropdown = (id) => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            [`dropdown${name}`]: !prevState[`dropdown${id}`] //dropdownA, dropdownB, dropdownC and so on
        }))
    }
```

this will also toggle it if the dropdown was clicked when the menu is open. But then I have few more dropdowns, other dropdown won't close if I open a dropdown, how to solve this? I do a "hacky" way mixing react with jquery in componentWillMount, binding click event on body, check if the dropdown item is visible, if yes close it.

My question is, is there any better practice to avoid using jquery?

Comment: can you provide an example of your app.js?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

My suggestion is that you use the synthetic events `onFocus` and `onBlur` to trigger open/close state. `onFocus` will trigger when the element is clicked and `onBlur` will trigger when "unfocusing" (clicking outside). See [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#focus-events).

Also `tabIndex` attribute/prop is needed for focus/blur to work on non input type elements.

I can recommend looking at the [source of react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/packages/react-select/src/Select.js) and how they handle focusing/bluring.

Here is an example, you can see a demo of it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/x7k1nx92mq?module=%2Fsrc%2FDropdown.js)

```
import React from "react";

class Dropdown extends React.Component {
  state = {
    open: false
  };

  toggleDropdown() {
    this.setState({ open: !this.state.open });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        style={{ border: "1px solid #CCC" }}
        onBlur={() => this.toggleDropdown()}
        onFocus={() => this.toggleDropdown()}
        tabIndex="0"
      >
        Dropdown
        {this.state.open && (
          <div>
            <div>Red</div>
            <div>Green</div>
            <div>Blue</div>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Dropdown;
```

Comment: @heyhugo do you know how to allow the children elements (`<div>Red</div>`) to be focasable as well without minimizing the parent?

Comment: @JohnCullen use node.contains() (browser DOM) API to check if the parent contains the clicked element. You can see how it can be done here: https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/src/Select.js#L223

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying to mimic the CSS pseudo-tag `focus-within` and I got it to a reasonable degree. The only aspect I can't really handle is tabbing out of the last element minimizing the drop down. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Ok not sure what the tabbing issue you have is but maybe this resource helps: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex

tabindex attribute = tabIndex prop in react

Comment: How would I go about implementing this if the button is not inside the dropdown?

Comment: @heyhugo it's cool but.. the dropdown doesn't closes if its clicked the second time. because it's already focus. How can I toggle with the focus?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [react-onclickoutside](https://github.com/Pomax/react-onclickoutside) library that abstracts the body event handling for you. You just have to wrap your component in their `onClickOutside` higher order component that will execute the `handleClickOutside` callback any time the click happens outside of the drop down. That way you can have a private "open" state in all dropdowns and don't care about how the handling is achieved.

The code might look like that:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import onClickOutside from 'react-onclickoutside'

class Dropdown extends Component {
    constructor() {
        this.state = {open: false}
    }

    // Method automatically executed by the library.
    handleClickOutside() {
        this.setState({open: false})
    }

    render() { ... }
}

export default onClickOutside(Dropdown)
```

Answer (score 1):

First we create the state with the open value being false so the dropdown is closed as default.  We will then add an event listener for click that will close the dropdown and remove the event listener after the dropdown is closed.  We then add an onClick event to our button to change the state from false to true using toggleOpen().  We'll then wrap our content in an if/or to check that the content opens:

```
`class Dropdown extends React.Component {

     constructor() {
         super();

         this.state = {
             open: false
         }
         this.toggleOpen = this.toggleOpen.bind(this);
         this.toggleClosed = this.toggleClosed.bind(this);
     }

    toggleOpen() {
        this.setState({ open: true }, () => {
            document.addEventListener('click', this.toggleClosed)
        })
    }

   toggleClosed() {
       this.setState({ open: false}, () => {
           document.removeEventListener('click', this.toggleClosed)
       })
   }

   render() {
       return(
           <div>
               <button onClick=({ this.toggleOpen })>
                   Dropdown
               </button>
               {
                    this.state.open
                    ? (
                          <span> Dropdown</span><br /><br />
                          <span> content</span><br /><br />
                      ) :
                      (
                          null
                      )
        </div>
   }
   }`
```